# AWS lambda in VPC can not connect with Elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS Lambda in a VPC, as I want to access Easticsearch. As I have defined the Lambda in VPC and to access public internet I have configured a NAT gateway. The Lambda needs to persists some data in Elasticsearch.

Now when I run the Lambda Java code - it gives below error

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to <ELASTIC SEARCH DOMAIN URL> failed: connect timed out.
```

- The elastic search code work with Lambda with VPC.
- As I have created a NAT gateway i have update the routing table too

Comment: Do you have separate public and private subnets? It sounds like it. Is it in your private subnet?

Comment: What about allowing access from the Lambda security group in the ElastiCache security group?  If both services use the same security group, the group must have a rule to allow inbound access to itself.

Comment: ElastiCache or Elasticsearch? You mention both. Is your (presumably) Elasticsearch service in the same VPC as the Lambda function? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with your Elasticsearch service? Please provide as much detail about your setup as possible so that we can assist you.